# limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

How can I find the limit to infinity of this function? As this is a $0/0$ equation, I tried using the L'Hôpital's rule in this but ended up making it more complex. I've also tried rationalising the denominator but it didn't lead to anywhere.

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}} $$

Comment: Rationalizing the denominator should solve the problem, lol...

Comment: After rationalizing, I get ((+2)^1/2−(+1)^1/2)*((+1)^1/2 + ()^1/2), which gives it the form of 0 * infinity. Don't know where to go from here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume WLOG $x\geq0$. Thus, $$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x}$$$$=(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x)(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+1})\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+1}}$$$$=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+1}}=1-\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sqrt{x+2} -\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1} -\sqrt{x}}\\
=\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}} -\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} -1}\\
\end{gather*}
(Taking $\sqrt{x}$ common from both numerator and denominator)

Now, from the binomial series expansion, $(1+ay)^{b} =1+aby$, when $y\to 0$

\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}} =1+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{x}\\
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} =1+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{x}\\
\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}} -\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} -1} =\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\left( 1+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{x}\right) -\left( 1+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{x}\right) -1} =1
\end{gather*}

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken; I question the validity of your analysis.  If I understand correctly, if you let $y = (1/x)$, then you are reasoning that as $y\to 0$, a polynomial in $y$ of degree > 1 (perhaps of infinite degree) may be estimated by the corresponding polynomial of degree 1.  Since, you in effect have similar polynomials in $y$, of degree $> 1$ in both the numerator and denominator, I see no way of justifying your approach.  Perhaps it is my inexperience.  If so, please edit your query to explain.

Comment: It occurs to me that if $p(y),q(y)$ are each polynomials in $y$, then $$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{ry + y^2 \times p(y)}{sy + y^2 \times q(y)} = \frac{r}{s},$$ by L'Hopital's rule.  If I have correctly interpreted your intent, then I think your query should be much more explicit in including the necessary details.

Comment: @user2661923 Well, I assumed that as x tends to infinity, its reciprocal would tend towards 0, and in which case, the binomial approximations would be perfectly valid.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, sir, I have seen, and replied after understanding both the comments :)

Comment: Then, what do you mean by "the binomial approximations would be perfectly valid"?  Could you please prove that in your query?  If it took me some work to understand your answer, the original poster and many other reviewers will not understand your reasoning.

Comment: @user2661923 (1+ax)^b=1+abx for small x...

Comment: You could just as easily say that $(1 + ax)^b = 1$, for small $x$.  You are (in effect) comparing the error that occurs in the numerator with the error that occurs in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\sqrt{x+k+1}-\sqrt{x+k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+k+1}+\sqrt{x+k}}\sim\dfrac1{2\sqrt x}$$